# curl Failed to connect Connection refused

Tags: php, curl, server, wamp

i'm trying to connect with curl on a server that has wamp installed but i get connection refused `Failed to connect to centrala.ratt.ro port 47654: Connection refused`and i don't know why. If i access the link in browser it works, with php curl it's not working. Here is my code:

```
$url = "http://centrala.ratt.ro:47654/webhook/coordonate.php"; 



$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 47654);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode ($result));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

// This should be the default Content-type for POST requests
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));

$rezult = curl_exec($ch);
echo $rezult;
if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looked at https://gustavostraube.wordpress.com/2016/08/31/debugging-requests-with-curl/;

```
/*
 * We're going to use the output buffer to store the debug info.
 */
ob_start();
$out = fopen('php://output', 'w');

$handler = curl_init($url);

/*
 * Here we set the library verbosity and redirect the error output to the 
 * output buffer.
 */
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_STDERR, $out);
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($handler);
fclose($out);
/*
 * Joining debug info and response body.
 */
$data = ob_get_clean();
$data .= PHP_EOL . $response . PHP_EOL;
echo $data;
```

Review / post the output for $out to determine next steps; If you can, you should attempt to run curl on the command prompt with the '-vvv' options to get similar output.

Comment: ```curl -vvv POST http://centrala.ratt.ro:47654
* getaddrinfo(3) failed for POST:80
* Couldn't resolve host 'POST'
* Closing connection #0
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'POST'
* About to connect() to centrala.ratt.ro port 47654 (#0)
*   Trying 86.125.113.237... Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host```

Comment: Try: `curl -vvv -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"key1\": \"value1\" }" http://centrala.ratt.ro:47654/webhook/coordonate.php` (on windows);  Right now I'm seeing it return a `200` result code and not returning additional content

Comment: from command on windows it's working. Than what is wrong with my script?

Comment: If it works on windows, and you're still getting `Connection refused` from PHP, try to add the $out as described above.  That should provide some idea of what's going on